# Impose required columns constraint in pandas read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to read a large CSV into a dataframe with the additional constraint that I want to fail *early* if certain columns are missing (since the input is not as expected), but I do want *all* the columns, not just the required columns, to be included in the Dataframe. In [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), it seems that I can use the `usecols` argument if I want to specify the subset of columns to read in, but the only obvious way I can see to check which columns will be in a dataframe I'm about to read is to actually read the file.

I've made a working first-pass version that reads the dataframe as an iterator, gets the first line, checks that the columns exist, then reads the file with the normal arguments:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

class MissingColumnsError(ValueError):
    pass

def cols_enforced_reader(*args, cols_must_exist=None, **kwargs):
    if cols_must_exist is not None:
        # Read the first line of the DataFrame and check the columns
        new_kwargs =  kwargs.copy()
        new_kwargs['iterator'] = True
        new_kwargs['chunksize'] = 1

        if len(args):
            filepath_or_buffer = args[0]
            args = args[1:]
        else:
            filepath_or_buffer = new_kwargs.get('filepath_or_buffer', None)

        df_iterator = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, *args, **new_kwargs)

        c = next(df_iterator)
        if not all(col in c.columns for col in cols_must_exist):
            raise MissingColumnsError('Some required columns were missing!')

        seek = getattr(filepath_or_buffer, 'seek', None)
        if seek is not None:
            if filepath_or_buffer.seekable():
                filepath_or_buffer.seek(0)

    return pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, *args, **kwargs)

in_csv = """col1,col2,col3\n0,1,2\n3,4,5\n6,7,8"""

# Should succeed
df = cols_enforced_reader(StringIO(in_csv), cols_must_exist=['col1'])
print('First call succeeded as expected.')

# Should fail
try:
    df = cols_enforced_reader(StringIO(in_csv), cols_must_exist=['col7'])
except MissingColumnsError:
    print('Second call failed as expected.')
```

This feels a bit messy to me and doesn't really handle all possible inputs for `filepath_or_buffer` (non-seekable streams, for example, or buffers where I'm not supposed to start at 0). Obviously I can tweak what I have here to my specific use case for the moment and be done with it, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this (preferably just using standard pandas functions) that works in *general*.

Answer (score 2):

You could just read one row and test if all required columns are present on that? For example:

```
import pandas as pd

required_cols = ['col1', 'col2']
cols = pd.read_csv('input.csv', nrows=1).columns

if all(req in cols for req in required_cols):
    print pd.read_csv('input.csv')
else:
    print "Columns missing"
```

---

To do this via a stream, an alternative approach would be to read it via a `csv.reader()`, this is compatible with `itertools.tee()`:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import tee
import csv

required_cols = ['col1', 'col2']

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_stream1, csv_stream2 = tee(csv_input, 2)
    header = next(csv_stream1)

    if all(req in header for req in required_cols):
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(csv_stream2)[1:], columns=header)
        print(df)
    else:
        print("Columns missing")
```

Comment: This is more or less what I'm doing in my question, but it does still require reading the file twice, which doesn't necessarily play nice with CSVs that are buffers and not paths. Ideally, I'd use something that reads the columns first, checks those, then either throws an error or continues going as expected.

Comment: I was going to suggest taking your stream and duplicating it using [`itertools.tee()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html?highlight=tee#itertools.tee) but I seem to remember pandas doesn't play ball with that.

Comment: Yeah, I think the answer to this one is actually "no, it's not possible to do it elegantly". The version with the csvreader has the downside that it ignores all arguments to pandas.read_csv. I think some combination of my version and your first version, plus a bunch more edge case checking might be the only way to make a generic function that does this.